# delete query is giving error but same condition works in select

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
delete from T_SEARCH_TABLES
where TABLE_NAME = 'D_VENDOR'
      and SEARCH_ID in(select distinct htvf.Value
                       from T_RESX_VALUES
                            cross apply dbo.func_split(T_RESX_VALUES.[key],'.') as htvf
                       where T_RESX_VALUES.value like '%Invoices - Activity (%'
                              and htvf.Position = '2'
                              and T_RESX_VALUES.[KEY] like 'SearchName.%'
                      )
      and SEARCH_TABLE_ID not in(select SEARCH_TABLE_ID
                                 from T_SEARCH_COLUMNS
                                );
```

Is giving error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'SearchName' to data type int.

But

```
select *
from T_SEARCH_TABLES
where TABLE_NAME = 'D_VENDOR'
      and SEARCH_ID in(select distinct htvf.Value
                        from T_RESX_VALUES
                            cross apply dbo.func_split(T_RESX_VALUES.[key],'.') as htvf
                        where T_RESX_VALUES.value like '%Invoices - Activity (%'
                              and htvf.Position = '2'
                              and T_RESX_VALUES.[KEY] like 'SearchName.%'
                       )
      and SEARCH_TABLE_ID not in(select SEARCH_TABLE_ID
                             from T_SEARCH_COLUMNS
                            );
```

is working fine what is the problem in it ?

Comment: Can you share the table scripts?

Comment: Well, my first idea would be that T_RESX_VALUES.[KEY] is actually an integer. I'm not sure why it is a problem in delete and not in select, though

Comment: T_RESX_VALUES.[KEY] is nvarchar(100)

Comment: Without the schema how are we supposed to help?

Comment: What happens with the `select` version if you uncomment out the last `not in` condition so your queries are actually searching for the same thing?

Comment: Do you have delete trigger that cause the error?

Comment: no i dont have a trigger for it

Comment: itsa the same query in delete and select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that at both DELETE and SELECT statements the first conditions of your inner WHERE CLAUSE

```
(T_RESX_VALUES.value like '%Invoices - Activity (%'and htvf.Position = '2')
```

were met?

Let me explain

I have run these two statements at my DB

```
select * from customers where cust_id = 0 and Cust_Name = 1

select * from customers where cust_id = 816171 and Cust_Name = 1
```

The Cust_Name column is of type varchar. My table contains one customer with ID = 816171 and Cust_Name = 'Mike' but no customers with ID = 0.

I got the following results:
The first query run ok but returned no rows

The second query returned the following error:

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Mike' to data type int.
```

It seems that sql-server doesn't try even to commit the conversion if the first condition is not met.

Actually the reason is that SQL doesn't always executes checks of where clauses in same order, the engine itself chooses every time the most optimized order.

You can read here more:
http://rusanu.com/2009/09/13/on-sql-server-boolean-operator-short-circuit/

Comment: Yes i am sure my condition meets the data requirement

Comment: does your Select statement returns any values?

Comment: Yes it does as expected

Comment: Try to run the SELECT statement without the and 'T_RESX_VALUES.[KEY] like 'SearchName.%'' condition. Does it return the same or more rows?

Comment: that is important to include for delete

Comment: can you give us some sample data from your tables, in order to make some testing?